# How to update widget based on Broadcast message?

Tags: android, widget, broadcast

I have a broadcast message from my service and it updates info in one of the activities but I would like it to update my Widget as well. How would I go about it?

Let's say there is a Broadcast in a system with action "ACTION" and it contains extra "TIME". How would I make the "TIME" appear in the widget? I have a clean class made by the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

you just need on action in *onReceive()* of your broadcast receiver make a *RemoteView*  and update widget:

```
public static final String ACTION = "ACTION";
public static final String TIME = "TIME";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction() != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);
            String time = intent.getStringExtra(TIME);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, time);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
        }
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```